# Is it ok to use count($arr) in loop conditions

Tags: php

I am wondering which way is better to use and why?

```
    $arr = array(); // some array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
        //some code
    }
```

or

```
    $arr = array(); // some array
    $cnt = count($arr);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i) {
        //some code
    }
```

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `echo` is faster than `print`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the biggest difference what you have to be aware of is in the first example if you modify the array.

As an example:

first:

```
<?php

    $arr = [1,2,3];
     for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
        echo "x". "<br />";
        array_pop($arr);
    }   

?>
```

Output:

```
x
x
```

Condition: `$i < count($arr)`

```
1. Iteration: 0 < 3  -> TRUE
2. Iteration: 1 < 2  -> TRUE
3. Iteration: 2 < 1  -> FALSE
```

second:

```
<?php

    $arr = [1,2,3];
    $c = count($arr);
     for($i = 0; $i < $c; ++$i) {
                    //^^ See here
        echo "x". "<br />";
        array_pop($arr);
    }   

?>
```

Output:

```
x
x
x
```

Condition: `$i < $c`

```
1. Iteration: 0 < 3  -> TRUE
2. Iteration: 1 < 3  -> TRUE
3. Iteration: 2 < 3  -> TRUE
4. Iteration: 3 < 3  -> FALSE
```

So as you can see in the first example the loop runs 1 iteration less than the other one! Why? Because it checks the condition in every iteration, so when you modify the source array now in the for loop the count will be different in every iteration opposed to that in the second example you count the array before the loop and the variable won't change in the for loop.

Besides this I think it's more a personal preference what you choose. (And if you want the most efficient one go for the second one where you only call `count()` once)

And if you want to take a look at the generated opcode of both examples, then the biggest difference is, that the second one makes 1 operation more than the first one where you don't assign the return of `count()`.

first:

```
number of ops:  11
compiled vars:  !0 = $arr, !1 = $i
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   INIT_ARRAY                                       ~0      
         1      ASSIGN                                                   !0, ~0
   4     2      ASSIGN                                                   !1, 0
         3  >   SEND_VAR                                                 !0
         4      DO_FCALL                                      1  $3      'count'
         5      IS_SMALLER                                       ~4      !1, $3
         6    > JMPZNZ                                        9          ~4, ->10
         7  >   PRE_INC                                                  !1
         8    > JMP                                                      ->3
   6     9  > > JMP                                                      ->7
        10  > > RETURN                                                   1
```

second:

```
number of ops:  12
compiled vars:  !0 = $arr, !1 = $cnt, !2 = $i
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   INIT_ARRAY                                       ~0      
         1      ASSIGN                                                   !0, ~0
   4     2      SEND_VAR                                                 !0
         3      DO_FCALL                                      1  $2      'count'
         4      ASSIGN                                                   !1, $2
   5     5      ASSIGN                                                   !2, 0
         6  >   IS_SMALLER                                       ~5      !2, !1
         7    > JMPZNZ                                        A          ~5, ->11
         8  >   PRE_INC                                                  !2
         9    > JMP                                                      ->6
   7    10  > > JMP                                                      ->8
        11  > > RETURN                                                   1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And could you tell please. How can I see the opcode of my php code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not hunting for the last millisec runtime, the first example is the more typical one. But it does check the size of the array with each iteration again, hence it is a little slower. But the code is nicer to read. So the first one is programmer book compatible, while the second one is already optimized (probably too early ;)

Answer (score 0):

**count** is *function* which called to calculate the number of element in array and you should not call a function repeatedly. if *space* is not issue then you should call this *function* one time and store returned value and then use that variable where you want.

- Know about [Count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)